# seeding user names for third party logins in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm building an MVC app and would prefer to use third party auth providers such as Microsoft and google. The only problem is that I don't want to just allow anyone to register to access my application. I'd prefer my friends give me their Microsoft email address, seed that information in my Db and then allow them to authenticate via Outh. Assuming this is possible how is it done?

Comment: This question is a very broad "How could this be done?" question. Are you able to reword it to be more specific? Code samples also help in guiding you.

Comment: Basically "how could it be done?" almost all of the tutorials online focus on enabling a site that uses registration which is not my use case. It seems logical that this is possible so if anyone has code example or know of a tutorial that covers this it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store a list of valid email addresses (from your friends) somewhere in the application.

If you have included the email address in the scope (say, for Microsoft) then you can check the email address against your list.

If this is being done using Asp.NET Identity, you can include the email address like this:

```
var microsoftOpts = new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = "your client id",
    ClientSecret = "your client secret"
};

microsoftOpts.Scope.Add("wl.emails");

app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(microsoftOpts);
```

Then in the ExcternalLoginCallback:

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
if (loginInfo == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}

// extract the email address of the external account
var email = loginInfo.Email;

if (!listOfValidEmailAddress.Contains(email))
{
    //not one of your friends, redirect to error page
}

//IS one of your friends, continue as normal.
```